# How can I use a QProgressDialog as a simple wait dialog without QProgressBar?

Tags: qt, qprogressbar

There is an operation in my application that can take up-to few minutes to finish. I wish to show a simple dialog box which opens when the operation begins, displays a simple wait message like 'Operation in progress..' and closes automatically when the operation finishes.

To implement above functionality, I am trying to make use of a QProgressDialog which does not have a QProgressBar. It seems to work fine but I am *unable to set the wait message*. Following is the code:

```
QProgressDialog progress(this);  
QLabel *lblCustom = new QLabel(&progress);  
progress.setBar(new QProgressBar());  
progress.setValue(0);  
progress.setLabel(lblCustom);  
progress.setLabelText("Operation in progress. Please wait...");  
progress.setMaximum(0);  
progress.setMinimum(0);  
progress.setModal(true);  
progress.setWindowTitle("Validate field data");  
progress.setCancelButton(0);  
progress.setFixedSize(400, 100);  
progress.setWindowFlags(progress.windowFlags() & ~Qt::WindowCloseButtonHint);  
progress.show();  
// operation  
progress.close();
```

Setting label text does not seem to work. Please let me know what is wrong here? I am relatively new to Qt.

[image: Dialog without wait message]

Comment: Why don't you just use the `QLabel` as your message? After all, any widget that is not a child of another will form a popup window.

Comment: Hi @RobbieE, I tried using QLabel to work as a popup. But, here again the message is _not_ appearing :) Can you please check what is wrong ? following is the code:  QLabel *lblCustom = new QLabel();
 lblCustom->setFixedSize(400, 80);
 lblCustom->setText("Operation in progress. Please wait...");
 lblCustom->show();
 // Some Operation .... 
 lblCustom->close();

Comment: I assume the problem is that the code at `// operation` blocks the event loop and thus the progress window never gets painted. You should implement lengthy operations asynchronously to avoid blocking the main thread.

Comment: You're not running the event loop.

Answer (score 2):

To solve the actual problem, I was used QLabel as a dialog instead of QProgressDialog and invoked QApplication::processEvents(), to make sure QLabel window gets painted with suitable text as well.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you create a new widget, then you can customize as you like. You can insert images and labels and you can create your own methods (including signals and slots). It will take a little longer to implement but it will be much more flexible and extensible.